# Performing permissions change ala chmod / attrib with Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions

I would like to do the equivalent of `chmod -w+r-x foo` or `attrib +R foo` in Windows Powershell. Putzing around, I notice a fairly gnarly `Set-Acl` function that looks *significantly* fancier than what I need.

How do I do `attrib +R foo` in Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) comes with Set-Writable (aliased to swr) and Set-ReadOnly (aliased to sro).  I use them both frequently.  Removing execute privileges does require a change to the ACLs however using Get-Acl/Set-Acl is painful.  I would use icacls.exe.

BTW if you don't want to mess with any 3rd party stuff, setting readonly to true/false is pretty easy:

```
Set-ItemProperty foo.txt IsReadOnly $true # or $false
```

Comment: Well that's handy, I should check those out. Maybe I could retire a bunch of my hacked together scripts.

Comment: There's some pretty neat stuff in PSCX. Definitely worth checking out.